# Keep getting "UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning" that throws me out of node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, terminal

I'm trying to connect to my server using Mongoose, and run my app.js file using Node. Initially it went okay, and my file was run on Node without problem, but later on I started getting "Unhandled Promise Rejection Warning" that throws me out of Node every time I'm trying to run the file.  These are the errors that I get in my terminal, every time I try to run 'node app.js':

```
(node:20496) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongooseServerSelectionError: connection timed out
    at new MongooseServerSelectionError (C:\Users\ינון\desktop\web-development\fruitsProject\node_modules\mongoose\lib\error\serverSelection.js:22:11)
    at NativeConnection.Connection.openUri (C:\Users\ינון\desktop\web-development\fruitsProject\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:823:32)
    at Mongoose.connect (C:\Users\ינון\desktop\web-development\fruitsProject\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:333:15) 
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\ינון\desktop\web-development\fruitsProject\app.js:3:10)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1178:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1002:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:901:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:74:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:18:47
(node:20496) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:20496) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Here's all of the code that I have in my app.js file (the file I'm trying to run with Node).

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/fruitsDB', {useUnifiedTopology: true, useNewUrlParser: true});

const fruitSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    rating: Number,
    review: String
  });

  const Fruit = mongoose.model("Fruit", fruitSchema);

  const fruit = new Fruit ({
      name: "Apple",
      rating: 7,
      review: "Pretty solid as a fruit"
  })

  //fruit.save();

  const personSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
      name: String,
      age: Number
  })

  const Person = mongoose.model("Person", personSchema);

  const person = new Person({
      name: "John",
      age: 33
  })

  //person.save();

  const kiwi = new Fruit ({
    name: "Kiwi",
    rating: 7,
    review: "it's okay"
})

const orange = new Fruit ({
    name: "Orange",
    rating: 4,
    review: "Ew"
})

const banana = new Fruit ({
    name: "Banana",
    rating: 2,
    review: "wtf"
})

// Fruit.insertMany([kiwi, orange, banana], function(err) {
//     if(err) {
//         console.log(err);
//     }
//     else {
//         console.log("Successfully saved all fruits to fruitsDB.");
//     }
// })

Fruit.find(function(err, fruits) {
    if(err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
    else {
        console.log(fruits);
    }
})



const findDocuments = function(db, callback) {
    // Get the documents collection
    const collection = db.collection('fruits');
    // Find some documents
    collection.find({}).toArray(function(err, fruits) {
      assert.equal(err, null);
      console.log("Found the following records");
      console.log(fruits)
      callback(fruits);
    });
}
```

Comment: Are you sure your mongodb instance is up and running? It could also be your connection string.

Comment: Grab [MongoDB Compass](https://www.mongodb.com/products/compass) and see if you can connect with your connection string.

Comment: Where do I see my connection string?

Comment: Are you actually running mongo locally? And please remove the ranting part about downvotes. I didn't downvote but looking at your editing history, the downvote was justified. Knowing SO, complaining will just get you more downvotes. Keep the question short and to the point

Comment: I have three tabs open in my terminal - the tab I where I run 'mongod', the tab where I run 'mongo', and the tab where I'm trying to run Node. If it matters, all three commands are run from the same directory of my project. I'll cut down my question and remove the part you're talking about, although I'd love if you could explain in my inbox what was so wrong with my editing history. to the point that I shouldn't be helped.

Comment: People on this site can be persnickety when it comes to voting. It isn't so much that they do not believe you should be helped. Don't take it personally.  

If you didn't alter your setup, your local connection string will be `mongodb://localhost:27017/databaseName` where `databaseName` is whatever you named your database. Running the command mongo will give you an interactive terminal to verify your mongo instance is running and that the database exists.